# Finding models inside a set of Polygons in GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, gis, geodjango

I have a bunch of polygon-based regions:

```
regions = Region.objects.filter(criteria=criteria)
```

The model is defined as such:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    poly = models.PolygonField()
```

I have a point-based model, like this one:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    point = models.PointField()
```

Is there a way to get all instances of Example that fall inside **any** of the polygons in the queryset?
I can't find any info related to this in the docs.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

models.py :

```
from django.contrib.gis import models

class Example(models.Model):
    point = models.PointField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

You build a multipolygon out of all those regions, and ask what example is inside that multipolygon

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import MultiPolygon

list_poly = [reg.poly for reg in Region.objects.filter(criteria=criteria)]
multipolygon = MultiPolygon(list_poly)
list_examples = Example.objects.filter(point__within=multipolygon)
```

Comment: Nice approach. I ended up using Q objects, but this is cleaner